# How to link Button click to datasource to run a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have figured out how to create the dropdown boxes, link them to their respective datasources, as well as create a datasource linked to the stored procedure. I can not figure out how to link the button to the datasource to run the stored procedure when it is clicked. I'm working with VS 2017.

HTML markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangeShiftStat.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    &nbsp; Shift&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ShiftDataSource" DataTextField="Shift" DataValueField="Shift">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp; New Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="StatusDataSource" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Status">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Change Status" />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ShiftDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TheBoardConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Shifts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StatusDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TheBoardConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Statuses]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RunSP" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TheBoardConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="changeshiftstat" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Shift" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="NewStat" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to submit an [sql command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) via the click event of the button. Set the CommandText to the name of your stored procedure and commandType to commandType.StoredProcedure. Depending on what you want to do, you can either open a reader as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx) or just execute the non-query command as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x06z3b.aspx) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The examples talk about getting results back.  I really do not need that. Would you be able to point me in the direction as to where i would put the code?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x06z3b.aspx for an example of how to execute a non query in sql. If you don't have any parameters, then just skip those lines.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.80).aspx <- This tutorial will show you how to add event handlers to your program. You will want a button click event.